# Is it possible to get access to http session from ashx http handler in sharepoint 2010+?

Tags: session, ashx

If so, do you just have to enable session for sharepoint and then implement `IReadOnlySessionState` on the handler class? I am on machines where I cannot enable session yet, and was hoping someone who knows could answer this for me.

Answer (score 1):

To start using Session State you need to Enable the Session State service using following Powershell command:

`Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision`

And in Web.Config you need to make sure:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
…
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
…
modules>
```

AND

`<pages enableSessionState="true"`

This works for Web Parts etc, I hope after that if you implement `IReadOnlySessionState`, it will work in Http Handler as well.